# How do I disable screen blanking in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, power-management, screensaver

I have a Nexus 7 on my desk which I am using as a "second" screen as I work. It's displaying useful data to me. As such I don't want the screen to blank at all as it's plugged into a charger and I want it to always be displaying something.

How can I disable the screen blanking so my screen always stays on, until I press the power button to blank it manually?

Comment: You might want to add how it's displaying meaningful data.  Is it acting as a peripheral somehow?  Running android?  Running U-Touch?  Those all have different answers.

Comment: You used to be able to do it in System Settings -> Battery, but it seems to have been removed

Comment: @hbdgaf I tagged it "ubuntu-touch" and wrote "Ubuntu Touch" in the title. This is ask *ubuntu*. I fail to see how anyone could think I'm talking about Android! :)

Comment: Fair enough.  I didn't look at the who posted it spot.  You'ld be surprised how many people don't know the difference between ubuntu for android and u-touch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be in System Settings -> Battery, once [Bug #1230345](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity8/+bug/1230345) is fixed.  Apparently the control over this is moving from powerd to unity8, and until that's done the option in System Settings [has been hidden](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~system-settings-touch/ubuntu-system-settings/trunk/revision/382).

Comment: For now you can open a shell and run "powerd-cli display on &"